# Rails Nested Associations and Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn arel/scopes in Rails..
I have the following models..

```
Class Category
  has_many :questions

Class Question
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :answers

Class Answer
  belongs_to :question
  # attributes: owner_name
```

I'm trying to find Categories that have answers with the owner_name, say "bob". For this I was thinking of adding a has_many :through relationship between Category and Answer and then accessing answers of a category using..

```
Category.find_each do |c|
  c.answers.find_by_owner_name("bob")
end
```

..but this seems like an overkill and is lengthy. Can I do this better using a scope defined in the Category class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find_each approach will definitely kill you performance-wise. You are right about creating a has_many :through relationship between Category and Answer. Once you have that it's straight-forward:

```
Category.joins(:answers).where("answers.owner_name = ?", "Bob")
```

Comment: the `category` and the `answer` model are not connected

Comment: Of course they are. A category has many answers through questions. That association is already in the current schema.

Comment: actually it isn't but, yeah with a through relationship this can work! also add a `.uniq`

Comment: this is so simple, i overlooked it, the initial question was including some funky relationship with `Patients, Doctors and Appointments`, and haven't thought it through after that

Comment: yeah, that initial schema was my bad. I still do need to add a has_many :through relationship though to make this answer work, right?

Comment: Thanks to @boudler, i didn't actually know that you could join `through` relationships.

Answer (score 0):

```
@categories = Answer.where(:owner_name => "Bob").collect(&:category)
```

You could use delegate to make this happen:

```
Class Answer
  belongs_to :question
  delegate :category, :to => :question, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Or if you don't want to use the `delegate` method, you could just do this:

```
@categories = Answer.where(:owner_name => "Bob").collect(&:question).collect(&:category)
```

Comment: hmm, well changing the schema can break dependencies so would want to avoid that.

Comment: so one patient has only one appointment in his life? and the physician sees multiple patients at once?

Comment: I changed the model names to suit the associations better.

Comment: Thanks but I'm having difficulty in seeing how to use the delegate to get what I need? Do I need to create a has_many through?

Comment: no, no need for it. Your `Question` model has a `category` method to return it's category, and this just delegates it to the `Answer` model. Now you can see in what category the `Answer` is like: `@answer.category` instead of `@answer.question.category`.

Comment: Great, i see it now, thanks! It's working. Can I change this to a scope somehow which really is the point of this exercise.

Comment: hm, a scope? to be honest i'm not really familiar with scopes but i guess you could do:
`scope :categories_by_owner_name, lambda {|owner_name| where("owner_name = ?", owner_name).collect(&:category)}`

Comment: No problem, but look at @boulder's answer